# Relative paths in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm having issues with relative paths when building a project.

Whereas the relative path seems to be supported under Linker/General, such as... "../../bin/myProxy.exe"

However when setting the Output Directory relative paths don't seem to be supported (it just adds the ../../ etc into the file path!).

Is this how it is supposed to work/any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is backwhack('\').. not to be confused with the standard [whack](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/w/whack.htm) ('/')

it needs to be backslashes: **..\..\**

Comment: Hmmm now I did try this... but it still seems to be doing it?

For example, when adding ..\..\ it simply does... C:\Path\To\..\..\something.lib ?

Comment: In Project Properties -> Build: Try using the BROWSE box next to the input and choosing "Select Folder" where you are attempting to output to

Comment: Also... not sure if you realize but C:\Path\To\..\..\ == C:\